# multiple LNK2019 errors ( __wassert, RegisterClassEx, CreateWindowEx,..)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line, linker

I try to compile and link my program using command-line link tool comming with Vsiaul Studio:

```
D:\Программы\textalign\textalign>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\link"/LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\amd64" /VERBOSE /NODEFAULTLIB /Entry:WinMain Kernel32.lib User32.lib Gdi32.lib libcpmt.lib main.obj
```

I use 64-bit libraries.

I get multiple linker errors: unresoved externals:

```
Запуск 1-го прохода (1-st pass)

Поиск библиотек (Libraries search)
    Поиск C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64\Kernel32.lib:
    Поиск C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64\User32.lib:
    Поиск C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64\Gdi32.lib:

    Поиск C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\amd64\libcpmt.lib:

Поиск библиотек завершен (Libraries search is finished)

1-ый проход завершен (1-st pass is finished)


Неиспользуемые библиотеки: (Unused libraries:)
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64\Kernel32.lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64\User32.lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64\Gdi32.lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\amd64\libcpmt.lib

main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__GetLastError@0 функции _WinMain@16
main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__FormatMessageW@28 в функции "void __cdecl OutputErrorMessage(unsigned long)" (?OutputErrorMessage@@YAXK@Z)
...
main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__MoveToEx@16 в функции "int __cdecl PrintText(struct HDC__ *,struct tagRECT)" (?PrintText@@YAHPAUHDC__@@UtagRECT@@@Z)
main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__TextOutW@20 в функции "int __cdecl PrintText(struct HDC__ *,struct tagRECT)" (?PrintText@@YAHPAUHDC__@@UtagRECT@@@Z)
...
main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__RegisterClassExW@4 в функции _WinMain@16
main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__CreateWindowExW@48 в функции _WinMain@16
main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__ShowWindow@8 в функции _WinMain@16
...
main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __wassert в функции _WinMain@16
main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ @__security_check_cookie@4 в функции "long __stdcall WindowProcedure(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProcedure@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ ___security_cookie в функции "long __stdcall WindowProcedure(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProcedure@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 28
(main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: unresolved external elements: 28)
```

I don't like those "unused libraries" section output, because it does look like it ignores my Kernel32.lib and other libraries.

What's even more cryptic:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__FormatMessageW@28 в функции "void __cdecl OutputErrorMessage(unsigned long)" (?OutputErrorMessage@@YAXK@Z)
```

That's not external function. Here's its code:

```
void OutputErrorMessage(DWORD err);
...
void OutputErrorMessage(DWORD err)
{
        LPTSTR buffer = NULL;
        DWORD bufSize = FormatMessage(
              FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER|FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM|FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        err,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&buffer,
        0,
        NULL);
        assert(bufSize);
        if (bufSize)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, buffer, _T("Could not create hwnd"), MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
        }
        LocalFree(buffer);
}
```

If this can help, here is the command I used to compile main.cpp into main.obj file:

```
D:\Программы\textalign\textalign>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\cl" /c /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include" "main.cpp"
```

All the libraries on those two paths are 64-bit libs.

EDIT: Now I have built the application but it does not run:

I've fixed the lib path and it linked fine with 32-bit libs.

I also tried to link with 64-bit libs but I get error, "no smdb120.dll" library. And there's only a 32-bit version of it on my PC. (I couldn't find anything in the Internet.) It links if I give a 64-bit linker this 32-bit library, but isn't it wrong to do so?

The problem is: the application (both 32-bit and 64-bit) doesn't create GUI, it runs as a background process with 0% processor time, so it does nothing at all.

The same application built with mingw (codeblocks ide) runs ok.

What can be a problem? How can I fix it?
I tried to remove `/NODEFAULTLIB` and add `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You are using 32-bit compiler, not 64-bit one. The latter is under `bin\amd64\cl`.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, for `_wassert`:  you are linking with `/nodefaultlib`, which suppresses the implicit link with the CRT, so you need to link explicitly with libcmt.lib.  For the other errors, you lib path is set incorrectly:  you're passing amd64 libraries to the x86 linker, so it'll just ignore them.

Comment: @James McNellis, I've fixed the lib path and it linked fine with 32-bit libs.
The problem is: the application (both 32-bit and 64-bit) doesn't create GUI, it runs as a background process with 0% processor time, so it does nothing at all.
The same application built with mingw (codeblocks ide) runs ok.
What can be a problem? How can I fix it?
I tried to remove `/NODEFAULTLIB` and add `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` but that doesn't solve the problem.
P.S.: I've updated the question.

Comment: Start the program under a debugger and step through the code to see what is going wrong.